# Is LIFT-web framework similar to ASP.net web forms?

Tags: lift

I have worked on the .NET side of things but I am looking at new open-source based web frameworks for a new project.

I looked at LIFT-web, Play, Ruby on Rails etc.  LIFT seems very promising for out of the box security and performance.  But it claims to have a new approach "view first" instead of MVC.  This sounds very similar to the ASP.net web forms paradigm, which was great for drag and drop development but had challenges in terms of testability and having control on what actually

I am wondering whether testing and having full visibility and control on the runtime behavior of LIFT will be difficult.  I will appreciate any feedback from people who have used LIFT, better still if they have used both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I can see why you think they might be similar, but in practice it's not really the case... not for larger applications anyway. If you're building a trivial application in a similar style to web forms, then you'll see similar issues. Lift snippets are in some respects similar to web forms user controls, but the latter are typically abused with munging all manner or content, request, state and so forth together which can indeed make things difficult to test. It's also possible to do that with Lift, as the framework won't stop you. However, idiomatically I wouldn't do that, as I try to ensure my snippets (user controls if you like) are referentially transparent NodeSeq => NodeSeq (xml to xml) functions. Snippets have an exceedingly close relationship with rendering content, and thats all. In addition, you may be interested to look more closely at the site map feature (many people overlook it), as there are some interesting ways in which that can be employed as a mini-controller w/r/t to the incoming request.

So, to try and qualify somewhat, you could indeed make ugly, untestable code with Lift - many people do - but if you keep your business logic properly separated out from the web tier and employ some developer discipline it's a manageable issue. In the main, the benefits largely outweigh the cons - especially in light of no other Scala web frameworks implementing the kinds of security or comet features Lift has.

The bottom line is that if you're building a CRUD application, then its highly likely Lift isn't for you. However, if you're building a rich, ajax or comet app, then its certainly going to be worth a look.

Hope that helps.

PS: You might be interested in checking out "Lift in Action"; it covers some of these topics - http://www.manning.com/perrett/